# How i can change animation speed in PIXI.js

Tags: pixi.js

Im using PIXI.js for create snow animation, but cant understand how to change speed of particular, or all animation speed?

codepen.io/venegrad/pen/RwLQmWR

I need to reduce speed on 3 or 4

Comment: If you want to increase how fast snow is falling then probably you want to increase value of  `particle.vy`  - so multiply it by something, or add some number to id etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the codepen.io link that you provided.
The code uses the first 2 variables for the speed of the snow animation:

```
const UPPER_LIMIT_Y = 1
const UPPER_LIMIT_X = 1
```

The `UPPER_LIMIT_Y` affects the vertical movement while the `UPPER_LIMIT_X` affects the sideways movement of the snow drops. If you want to change how fast the snow falls, you can reduce the `UPPER_LIMIT_Y` and `UPPER_LIMIT_X` into values between 0 and 1 (ex: 0.5). I suggest you temporarily change the variable `COLOR` at line 7 to 0x000000 to make the snowdrops more visible while testing the speed changes.